# flutter android studio 4.1 unable to locate adb

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-virtual-device

I know this question exists a lot on StackOverflow but none of the solutions I found seem to work.

### The problem

#### Run without project or with android project

I ofcourse need to select the correct API version but the AVD starts without any problem.

#### Run with flutter project

I get the error message "unable to locate adb" when starting up the AVD. The device boots anyway and I can run my apps on it but the error is annoying so I would like to get rid of it.

Also when i open the `build.gradel` file, I get the warning that the sync failed (see image below). When looking in the logs, I see again a lot of: `2020-11-06 14:50:31,561 [4185024]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found`

[image: Gradle project sync failed.]

### What I have tried

- check the adb.exe file in appdate (however that could not be the problem since it works with an android project)
- use 3 different api versions:28, 29, 30 (in the gradel file I see `minSdkVersion 21` and `targetSdkVersion 29`)
- resolve errors in `build.gradle`: `GradleNotFoundException` became `FileNotFoundException`

About Android studio:

- Android Studio 4.1
- Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6858069, built on September 23, 2020
- Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64
- VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- Windows 10 10.0